# How to pass an arbitrary number of the same type arguments to a method using varargs?

Tags: java, arrays, parameter-passing

These arguments are specified by three dots after the type. but i don't know what mean of `...` in the method

```
public static void printNumberOfArguments(int... numbers) {
    System.out.println(numbers.length);
}
```

and also in documentation

```
public static void method(long.. vararg) { /* do something */ }
```

this is wrong i don't know why?

Comment: *"this is wrong i don't know why?"* Mainly because you used two dots instead of three.

Comment: the dots mean  : any amount, passed as separate arguments, like `printNumberOfArguments(5, 6, 6, 7)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to pass an arbitrary number of the same type of arguments to a method using the special syntax named varargs (variable-length arguments). These arguments are specified by three dots after the type. In the body of the method, you can process this parameter as a regular array of the specified type.

Your method takes an integer vararg parameter and outputs the number of arguments in the standard output using the length property of arrays.

`...` is a  special syntax used here to specify a vararg parameter.

i am trying to provide you both types or passing varargs in methods in java:

**incorrect example:**

```
public static void method(double... varargs, int a) { /* do something */ }
```

**The correct version of the method is:**

```
public static void method(int a, double... varargs) { /* do something */ }
```

Comment: happy to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

A variable-length argument is specified by three periods(`…`).

you can invoke the method passing several integer numbers or an array of ints. these some examples will help you to understand this:

```
printNumberOfArguments(1);
printNumberOfArguments(1, 2);
printNumberOfArguments(1, 2, 3);
printNumberOfArguments(new int[] { }); // no arguments here
printNumberOfArguments(new int[] { 1, 2 });
```

This code outputs:

```
1
2
3
0
2
```